# There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/NotifyFullScreen that could accept the message

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a problem where the above exception is being thrown. I have created a server and a client in code for interprocess communication.

The server looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INotifyFullScreen
{
    [OperationContract]
    void NotifyAndonFullScreen();
}

public class NotifyFullScreen : INotifyFullScreen
{
    public void NotifyAndonFullScreen()
    {
        MainWindow.CurrentInstance.NotifyFullScreen();
    }
}

//...NotifyFullScreen() implemented in another class

using (
    var host = new ServiceHost(
    typeof(NotifyFullScreen), new[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/NotifyFullScreen") }))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(INotifyFullScreen), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "NotifyFullScreen");

    host.Open();
    app = new App();
    app.Run();
    host.Close();
}
```

...and the client looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface INotifyFullScreen
{
    [OperationContract]
    void NotifyAndonFullScreen();
}
```

//..

```
var pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<INotifyFullScreen>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new
    EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/NotifyFullScreen"));
var notifyProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

try
{
    notifyProxy.NotifyAndonFullScreen();
    pipeFactory.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception!");
    EventTrace.Default.LogException(ex);
}
```

Every time I try to call a method on the client (on notifyProxy), I get the above exception.

What am I doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Mark

Comment: No firewall involved ?

Comment: `app.Run()`: Is it possible that is exiting and so your server is actually closing the connection?  If not, I would definitely check your firewall

Comment: You say client and server - you **do know** that `net.pipe://` in WCF only works on the same machine - right? It's **not** capable of inter-machine communication ...

Comment: Yes I know that. It's for interprocess communication on the same machine. I have checked and the app.Run() is exiting and behaving as expected.

Comment: Actually I discovered the problem. I have two apps, App1 and App2, say. Each opens a channel to the other. When I comment out the server code for the other direction, the above code works. The question then is how do I have two applications, each hosting a WCF service?